# A Part of the SVG image is not showing up on WordPress website (Using Elementor)

Tags: wordpress, svg, elementor

I'm having trouble with an SVG file that I uploaded to my WordPress website using Elementor. The file seems normal in the media library but when I add it to the content, most of it is gone.

SVG image Before adding to the content

[image: 1]

SVG image After

[image: 2].

**Note: I added 12 other SVG files but none of them had this issue.

I'm not a programmer, but I read in other posts that you need to do something with the source code of the SVG, but I couldn't really understand anything. I tried reading the other posts, but the code wasn't similar in the least.

Here's the SVG file's code:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.3.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#5BBC96;}
        .st1{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
    </style>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M56.39,243.9c-2.15,0-4.21-1.22-5.17-3.3c-1.33-2.85-0.09-6.24,2.76-7.57c0.77-0.36,77.98-36.67,120.21-85.04
            c46.73-53.54,73.12-94.48,88.24-136.9c1.06-2.97,4.31-4.52,7.29-3.45c2.97,1.06,4.51,4.32,3.46,7.29
            c-15.63,43.84-42.66,85.88-90.4,140.56c-43.84,50.22-120.74,86.37-123.99,87.88C58.01,243.73,57.2,243.9,56.39,243.9z"/>
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0.8632" y1="23.4607" x2="276.5694" y2="299.167">
            <stop  offset="5.327789e-09" style="stop-color:#5BBC96"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#515BA8"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <path class="st1" d="M298.74,277l-23.77,23l0.05-16.72c0-1.13-0.92-2.05-2.06-2.05l-253.27-0.78h-0.37V26.12
            c0-1.13-0.92-2.04-2.04-2.04H0.56L23.63,0.69c0.91-0.92,2.4-0.92,3.3,0l23.08,23.38H33.29c-1.13,0-2.04,0.91-2.04,2.04v242.44
            L273,269.3c1.14,0,2.07-0.91,2.08-2.04l0.05-16.72l23.62,23.15C299.68,274.61,299.67,276.09,298.74,277z M90.19,234.83
            c-15.27,0-27.68-12.42-27.68-27.68c0-15.27,12.42-27.68,27.68-27.68c15.26,0,27.68,12.42,27.68,27.68
            C117.86,222.42,105.45,234.83,90.19,234.83z M90.19,193.73c-7.4,0-13.43,6.02-13.43,13.43c0,7.4,6.02,13.42,13.43,13.42
            c7.4,0,13.42-6.02,13.42-13.42C103.61,199.75,97.59,193.73,90.19,193.73z M169.61,166.78c-15.27,0-27.68-12.42-27.68-27.68
            s12.42-27.68,27.68-27.68c15.26,0,27.68,12.42,27.68,27.68S184.87,166.78,169.61,166.78z M169.61,125.67
            c-7.4,0-13.43,6.02-13.43,13.43c0,7.4,6.02,13.43,13.43,13.43c7.4,0,13.42-6.02,13.42-13.43
            C183.04,131.7,177.01,125.67,169.61,125.67z M184.4,90.31c-8.81,0-15.98-7.17-15.98-15.98c0-8.81,7.17-15.98,15.98-15.98
            c8.81,0,15.98,7.17,15.98,15.98C200.37,83.14,193.21,90.31,184.4,90.31z M184.4,69.75c-2.52,0-4.58,2.05-4.58,4.58
            c0,2.52,2.05,4.57,4.58,4.57c2.52,0,4.58-2.05,4.58-4.57C188.97,71.81,186.92,69.75,184.4,69.75z M237.13,141.58
            c-8.81,0-15.98-7.17-15.98-15.98c0-8.81,7.17-15.98,15.98-15.98c8.81,0,15.98,7.17,15.98,15.98
            C253.11,134.41,245.94,141.58,237.13,141.58z M237.13,121.03c-2.52,0-4.58,2.05-4.58,4.58c0,2.52,2.05,4.57,4.58,4.57
            s4.58-2.05,4.58-4.57C241.71,123.08,239.65,121.03,237.13,121.03z M154.58,213.32c-8.81,0-15.98-7.17-15.98-15.98
            c0-8.81,7.17-15.98,15.98-15.98c8.81,0,15.98,7.17,15.98,15.98C170.56,206.16,163.39,213.32,154.58,213.32z M154.58,192.77
            c-2.52,0-4.58,2.05-4.58,4.58c0,2.52,2.05,4.58,4.58,4.58c2.52,0,4.58-2.05,4.58-4.58C159.15,194.82,157.1,192.77,154.58,192.77z
             M104.69,170.56c-8.81,0-15.98-7.17-15.98-15.98c0-8.81,7.17-15.98,15.98-15.98s15.98,7.17,15.98,15.98
            C120.67,163.39,113.51,170.56,104.69,170.56z M104.69,150c-2.52,0-4.58,2.05-4.58,4.58s2.05,4.58,4.58,4.58
            c2.52,0,4.58-2.05,4.58-4.58S107.21,150,104.69,150z M249.38,100.26c-15.26,0-27.68-12.42-27.68-27.68s12.42-27.68,27.68-27.68
            c15.27,0,27.68,12.42,27.68,27.68S264.65,100.26,249.38,100.26z M249.38,59.16c-7.4,0-13.42,6.02-13.42,13.43
            c0,7.4,6.02,13.43,13.42,13.43c7.4,0,13.43-6.02,13.43-13.43C262.81,65.18,256.79,59.16,249.38,59.16z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Any help would be wonderful. The website is [NumXL](https://numxl.com/) if it might help in any way. If the information is not enough, please let me know and I'll immediately try to provide it.

I hope this makes sense, Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you have the same classes  (.st0, .st1) with different styles in the other svg elements. Or maybe you have a repeated gadient id

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for the quick reply. I think what you're saying is correct. The terms (.st0, .st1) are being used across all of the SVG files (This one, and the other 12). I changed the numbers in this file (i.e., .st2 & .st3 instead of .st0 & .st1) and the image worked for a little bit.

Then I changed another file from .st0 to .st4, as it also had issues, but this made the first image disappear completely.

I'm not sure what went wrong here. Also, I'm super slow in coding so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Hmm. I re-changed .st2 & .st3 to .st6 & .st7, and the image just worked again.

I think the issue is solved now. Thanks a lot, @enxaneta.